# PHP split string into tokens and tags

Tags: php, arrays

I have a string that needs to be separated (with PHP) into two arrays: tokens and tags.
Let's say this is the string:
*radioed/JJ to/TO earth/NN and/CC the/DT control/NN room/NN here/RB ./PUN*
I need two arrays, like so:

```
$_tokens = array("radioed","to","earth","and","the","control","room","here",".");
$_tags   = array("JJ","TO","NN","CC","DT","NN","NN","RB","PUN");
```

This means that since each phrase is in this format: *token/tag*
I basically need to do this as quickly as possible. Plus, I have some token/tag combinations that might be unsafe to directly place into a string (i.e. *"/PUQ*, where the quotation mark " is the token and PUQ is the tag), so I need to be able to escape these somehow.
Can anybody please suggest an efficient and fast method of doing this?
Thanks!

Comment: Is there something about Joseph's answer that doesn't satisfy?

Answer (score 1):

```
$sets = explode(' ', $string);

foreach ($sets as $set)
{
    list($_tokens[], $_tags[]) = explode('/', $set);
}
```

See it here in action: http://codepad.viper-7.com/A3ZGA0